# Can any package can be both managed, and installable in production, without requiring appexchange security review?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, security-review, beta-managed-package

Can any package can be both managed, and installable in production without appexchange security review? Assume a beta tester wants to beta the managed app in production.

According to "**Beta Versions of Managed Packages**

> Beta packages can be installed in sandbox or Developer Edition organizations, or test organizations furnished through the Environment Hub only.
>   source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_about_beta_packages.htm

Curious if there are any other options, but must be both managed (hidden) and skip appexchange security review (too soon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different things here.

1. Beta Versions of Managed Packages(These can be private manage packages or App exchange managed packages. **Private one's doesn't need to go through security review**. EX: You can work with a vendor to build some functionality specific to your needs and they can do it as a private manage package for you.)
2. AppExchange Security Review

[**Beta Versions of Managed Packages:**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_about_beta_packages.htm) A beta package is an early version of a managed package that is uploaded in a Managed - Beta state. The purpose of a Managed - Beta package is to **allow the developer to test their application** in different Salesforce organizations and to share the app with a pilot set of users for evaluation and feedback.

[**AppExchange Security Review:**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_guidelines.htm) We want Lightning Platform to be a safe and reliable platform for our customer’s core business applications. To promote trust, all apps and components that are distributed to customers undergo a comprehensive security review. Your offering must **meet or exceed the requirements set by our security review team before it can be distributed**(Unless its a private managed packed specific to the vendor only that doesn't want it on app exchange). After approval, apps and components are also periodically retested.

To your question:
No you can't install it in production org and your're not supposed to.

[More about packages here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/planning_managed_package_release.htm) : you can choose to make your package managed release and decide not to make it a public listing in app exchange. **In your case your'e looking for private released manage packages**

> Note: Unfortunately i didn't find a source that says betas can't be or
>   can be installed in production org!

Comment: Can you share your source for "No you can't install it in production org" ?  Looking for any way to install a _managed_ package into another _production_ org without having to do the security review.   You say "not supposed to" but the use-case for doing such is that the package makes use of a query that can only be performed in production.  That is the package only works in production orgs because the data it queries only exists in production orgs.

Comment: @PeterNoges You can turn your managed package into a released managed package and install it in a production org. You don't have to make it an app exchange listing. Only app exchange apps need security review. Will update the answer in a while

Comment: Accepting answer with the assumption that this is true: " You can turn your managed package into a released managed package and install it in a production org. You don't have to make it an app exchange listing. "    thank you!

Comment: @PeterNoges Yes it's true as i have worked with couple of packages myself!

Comment: were they private and did they skip appexchange security review?

Comment: Yes they are private! And they didn't go through security review.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84102/discussion-between-codeyinthecloud-and-peter-noges).